# Atlassian Bamboo deployment Plan with Artifactory-artifacts

Tags: deployment, artifactory, bamboo

Is there a way to make a deployment plan use artifacts from Artifactory rather than only shared artifacts from build plans in Bamboo?

I could only find the `Artifactory Plugin` for Bamboo, but that doesn't seem like it does, what I need.

Comment: The Artifactory plugin sure does what you need. Which build tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using Maven. As far as I could see, the plugin only allows me to deploy into artifactory, but not get artifacts from there and deploy them with a deployment plan.

Comment: When using Maven, the declared dependencies in pom file will be retrieved from Artifactory. Isn't it what you look for?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to deploy artifacts from Artifactory onto another machine with a Bamboo deployment-plan.

Comment: Got it. With any other supported build server we have generic resolution feature to define which artifacts you want to download from Artifactory (as a first step, prior to deployment), but currently not with Bamboo.